# The animation, flashlight and sound are not simultaneously working

Tags: java, android

I am working a assignment for my subject but i encountered a problem that the application i am working has not working in a way i want. first the problem is The Flashlight will blink first and after blinking the animation and sound will work at the same time. What i want is three of them will work simultaneously. This is the code.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wangwang);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            animationblink();
            blinkFlash();
            mp.start();                 
        }
    });

}

private void animationblink(){
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.blink);
    image.startAnimation(animation1);

    ImageView image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    Animation animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.blink);
    image1.startAnimation(animation2);

    ImageView image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    Animation animation3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.blink);
    image2.startAnimation(animation3);
}

private void blinkFlash()
{
    String myString = "010101";
    for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
        if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {        
                cam = Camera.open();
                p = cam.getParameters();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                cam.setParameters(p);
                cam.startPreview();
                status=true;
        }
        else {
                cam.stopPreview();
                cam.release();
                status=false;
            }
        }
    }
```